# How to connect an Intel RealSense camera to a raspberry pi 4 with ROS Kinetic?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm working on a robotics-related project and I want to connect an *Intel RealSense d435* camera to a *raspberry pi 4* with *ROS Kinetic*.

Any links on how to do that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/378831/how-to-connect-an-intel-realsense-camera-to-a-raspberry-pi-4-with-ros-kinetic?/) by [Beedz98](https://answers.ros.org/users/74923/beedz98/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-05-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey there,

Over here you will get the important link for real sense support. Another thing, you have to also put the RealSense™ SDK 2.0 library in your raspberry pi every thing will be explained in the below link.

https://github.com/IntelRealSense/realsense-ros

---

Originally posted by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) with karma: 1622 on 2021-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0